# How does Freedom of Movement work when grappling

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, grapple

Let's say I cast Freedom of Movement on myself. The next round I initiate grapple, can I initiate a grapple? and if successful would that result in the opponent being grappled and myself free of the grappling penalty (which normally one would suffer a -20 penalty to try to succeed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freedom of movement does not make your character immune to the *grappled* condition. Meaning that if you initiated the grapple, you still gain the grappled condition.

> All combat maneuver checks made to grapple the target automatically fail.

But any attempts to *revert the grapple* will automatically fail.